# How to run (execute) .sql file in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

I have a `Orders_SPs.sql` file.

Its purpose is to add a new stored procedure inside my existing `Northwind` database which is 
running on SQL Server 2005 and I also have SQL Server Management Studio.

But I don’t know how to execute that `.sql` file so it can add list of stored procedures in my existing `northwind` database from `Orders_SPs.sql` file.

Thanks….

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Launch SQL Server Management Studio
2. Make sure you're in the right database
3. Choose from menu: `File > Open > File`
4. Find and select your `orders_sps.sql` file
5. From the menu, choose `Query > Execute` (or press F5)

Answer (score 2):

Open the file in SQL Server Management Studio and hit F5.

Answer (score 2):

Open Sql Server Management Studio. Once opened, open your `.sql` file by clicking File-->Open.

Select the `NorthWind` from the Database list that appears on the tool bar. Now press F5.

It will run the SQL statements on your .sql file and create the stored procs.